# Algorithm for template argument deduction (as strings)?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, compiler-construction

For some reason, I want to implement something simliar to the what C++ compilers used to deduce template arguments. With a known set of template parameters like

"T0", "T1", "T2"...

Given 2 strings like:

```
str_param = "vector<T0>"    
str_arg = "vector<float>"
```

The result should be that "T0" is mapped to "float":

```
map["T0"]=="float"
```

I don't need a full-featured template preprocessor, which means, I'll be satisfied if I can just handle the cases where the template argument can be literally deduced. No need to consider things like "typedef" in the context.
In other words, if I use the resulted map to replace template parameters in **str_param**, it should become **str_arg**. If that is not possible, I consider it as "fail to match".

I currenlty have problem handling cases like:

```
str_param = "T1*"    
str_arg = "int**"
```

Where expected result is:

```
map["T1"]=="int*"
```

My algorithm mistakes it as:

```
map["T1"]=="int"
```

Putting my poor algorithm here:

```
std::vector<std::string> templ_params({"T1"});
std::vector<std::string> templ_args(templ_params.size());
std::string str_param = "T1*";
std::string str_arg = "int**";
const char* p_str_param = str_param.c_str();
const char* p_str_arg = str_arg.c_str();
while (*p_str_param != 0 && *p_str_arg != 0)
{
    while (*p_str_param == ' ' || *p_str_param == '\t') p_str_param++;
    while (*p_str_arg == ' ' || *p_str_arg == '\t') p_str_arg++;
    if (*p_str_param == 0 || *p_str_arg == 0) break;
    if (*p_str_param != *p_str_arg)
    {
        std::string templ_param;
        std::string templ_arg;
        while (*p_str_param == '_' ||
            (*p_str_param >= 'a' && *p_str_param <= 'z') ||
            (*p_str_param >= 'A' && *p_str_param <= 'Z') ||
            (*p_str_param >= '0' && *p_str_param <= '9'))
            templ_param += *(p_str_param++);
        while (*p_str_param == ' ' || *p_str_param == '\t') p_str_param++;
        char end_marker = *p_str_param;
        const char* p_str_arg_end = p_str_arg;
        while (*p_str_arg_end != end_marker) p_str_arg_end++;
        while (*(p_str_arg_end - 1) == ' ' || *(p_str_arg_end - 1) == '\t') 
            p_str_arg_end--;
        while (p_str_arg<p_str_arg_end) templ_arg += *(p_str_arg++);
        for (size_t i=0; i < templ_params.size(); j++)
        {
             if (templ_params[i]==templ_param)
             {
                 templ_args[i]=templ_arg;
                 break;
             }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        p_str_param++;
        p_str_arg++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your algorithm? Code?

Comment: Hi, Kuba, I don't ask questions here very much, hesitating if it is good to put about 100 lines of code here. Should I put it into the question or the comment area?

Comment: The 100 lines are too much but would be acceptable. Most likely the algorithm could be simplified – and make sure it’s written in actual C++, not just C compiled with a C++ compiler. Modern C++ is about as concise as Python: leverage that to make your algorithm shorter. Use type deduction, algorithms, range-for, standard containers, and avoid boilerplate. My bet is that your existing algorithm will fit in 50 lines and be easier to understand :)

Comment: yea, I over-estimated it, but still looks bulky.

Comment: Consider regex. Replace each occurrence of `Tn` with a capture group and you're done.

Comment: Do you want to consider real C++ constructs like `const int` equals `int const`?

Comment: @grek40 No, just literal. What I want is that, if I replace T0,T1... with the results, the 2 strings should match literally. If that is not possible, consider it as fail.

Comment: You could start by tokenizing your input... from `"vector<T0*>"` to `["vector", "<", "T0", "*", ">"]`. Refactor the code to create a token list into a separate function to reduce the amount of code inside your main algorithm function.

Comment: @grek40  I'll try it!